# What are the most profitable meals and elixirs I can cook?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I know how to [make delicious food and handy elixirs.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302008/how-do-i-cook-meals) I've also found that I have a ton of some ingredients, while others are more scarce. And most importantly, rupees seem *extremely* scarce this early on in the game.

I've also noticed that cooked food tends to sell for much more than the cost of the component ingredients. What recipes offer the best margins in this respect? I'm curious about recipes that offer high yield using commonly farmable ingredients like Bokoblin parts and butterflies and apples and bird legs, but also especially any that offer a high multiplier on the value of rupees spent purchasing component ingredients, if any.

Comment: 5 raw prime meat as one meal IIRC sells for 200+. That's all I got. Mineral farming was primarily how I made my money.

Comment: Don't ever sell your minerals at shops or otherwise use them in elixirs. They're worth more when sold to Ramella at Goron City.  IIRC, I got 10k rupees for selling her 10 diamonds.  The only catch is you she'll only by in batches of 10.

Comment: What @JeffMercado mentions turns mostly irrelevant once you've got the hang of fighting Taluses, though. In other words, start hunting Taluses and money becomes an absolute non-issue. Not an answer, but solves the actual issue behind why it was asked. EDIT: Oh, and Guardians, walking ones in particular. Ancient Cores (and Giant Cores especially) sell really well, so practice your parry.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The name, effects, and image of the food or elixir you produce is not important. The sell value of your cooking is entirely dependent on only two factors:

- The value of the ingredients you use
- How many ingredients you use

The price is determined by the following formula:

1. Add the value of the ingredients together.
2. Multiply this by:

   - 1.5 if you used one ingredient
   - 1.75 if you used two
   - 2.05 for three
   - 2.4 for four
   - 2.8 for five
3. Round the resulting number to the next ten. (101 -> 110, 87 -> 90, etc)

Here's an example:

You cook four Gourmet Meats. Each meat sells for 35 rupees. Add them together and you get 140. Multiply this by 2.4 because you use four ingredients. This gives you 336, so you need to round it up to the next ten, which is 340, the sale price.

So the **most profitable meals and elixirs you can cook are simply the ones made with five of the most expensive ingredients you can find.**
Just make sure they actually produce something edible, because if you end up with "Dubious Food" or "Rock-Hard Food", they will sell for next to nothing.

Source: [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75108593)

Comment: That's the formula I was looking for! (Though Gourmet Meat in particular is a bad idea then. There's a dude who buys those for much much more raw!)

Comment: I'm trying to find a list of ingredients that also shows sell value, but none of the ones I've found have that information.

Comment: If this formula is correct, you could cook four 2-rupee items seperately and gain twice as much value as you'd get by cooking them all together. Cooking 1-rupee items seperately would be even more profitable, but I'm not sure if those exist (and it'd be rather time consuming).

Comment: Great info!  But +1 to what @Andii said - while combining 5 ingredients generates the highest possible value for a *single* dish, the most *profitable* way to turn a fixed list of ingredients into money - the OPs goal - is actually to cook each one separately, I think?

Comment: @Jaydles The math only works for ingredients that are worth 1 or 2 rupees though. For anything that's worth more, the multipliers make multi-ingredient food more profitable. (After some checking, apparently the only items worth less than 3 rupees are ones you can't cook by themselves anyway, so it turns out my previous comment is actually kinda useless.)

Comment: It seems that dragon pieces and star fragments are exempt from this formula. Despite some of them being worth upwards of 300 rupees, including them in a dish doesn't seem to increase the dish's value by much, if at all.

Comment: Note that the final rounding is applied to a floored value, so combined ingredient value of 18 times 2.8 is 50.4, but the sale price remains 50. 15 and 22 are good high-gain combined ingredient values to cook with very common ingredients. 5 apples/mushrooms or four 4 rupee items and a 6 (I like snails and nightshade as I ended up with a great deal of both and I can use it to sneak if I haven't sold it).

Answer (score 14):

For meals, [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5xlois/rupee_making_101_no_story_spoilers/) describes a good way to make money. It describes getting lots of boar and deer meat, then making 5-meat skewers (use the same time of meat for each, if possible). Supposedly, the deer skewers sell for 210 and the boar meat ones sell for 120, and this is one of the get rich quick schemes the game offers.

From the post, here is a fast way to gather meat:

> Near Hateno Village, there is farmer named Dantz up on the large hillside pitching hay under a horse stable who offers a mini-game to hunt deer that can be spammed and will reward you with 5 rupees or 20 rupees depending on the number of deer you kill in the time limit.

This by itself is not the money maker, though. All the meat you get from the animals you kill is. To ensure maximum meat gain, a three-spread-shot bow is the best choice. However, you can also get a Soldier's Bow on the crate of the east side of the Tabantha Bridge Stable, which will kill the animals in one shot.

It's recommended to either wear the full Sheikah set or get other stealth buffs (potions, etc) to make this easier.

Comment: You actually can quote the Reddit post for more upvotes.  Right now it is a bit too close to a link answer.  Although the important bits are available, but a lot of very useful information are in the link.

Comment: This is helpful relative to the end goal of "make lots of money", but neatly sidesteps my actual question of what's *most profitable* by simply pointing out *what's abundant*.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz abundant is relative. Doing this minigame multiple times means that these particular items are abundant. Regardless of the minigame, all wild creatures drop one of 3 tiers of meat, I believe, so the answer is still the same, just slower, if you choose to kill animals outside of the minigame.

Comment: Sure. My point is that this sidesteps the question; what I'm curious about is what the most profitable *transformation* of that meat is. Does salting it make it more valuable, for example? (if all sale prices are simply a flat multiplier on base ingredient value, well, that leaves your answer as the best, but I've seen no evidence of that!)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I believe using raw ingredients is the way to go. AFAIK salt doesn't increase the cost, just the effect: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302879/does-salting-your-cooking-change-the-effects-regen-hearts-of-a-recipe

Answer (score 11):

I have found that creating elixirs using specific monster parts yields extremely expensive potions. I've experimented with several parts, but it seems like the **monster guts** are the most profitable. Combine 4 guts with 1 bug/frog/etc to create an elixir. The effect of the elixir doesn't matter, since your goal is to make money. (To maximize profits, the effect ingredient should be something worth more money, such as a hearty lizard or a tireless frog; however, you'll only be making an extra 50 or so rupees, so it's probably not worth using rare ingredients here - stick to darners and fireflies.)

You can use any guts you find, but in my opinion the most cost effective are Molduga and Lynel guts. When combining 4 guts with 1 elixir ingredient, the resulting potions will be worth about 1200 rupees (300 per gut) or 2400 (600 per gut) for Molduga or Lynel guts respectively.

---

Whatever you do, do not use star fragments or dragon pieces in your crafted food/elixirs if your goal is profit. Even though the base value of these items is very high, for some reason this value doesn't seem to get included in the price of the resulting food item.

Comment: Just want to add I tried using the Monster Extract in place of one gut and it wasn't worth doing either. Hinox Guts were far less valuable than Lynel but worth using them up if you have too.

Comment: I've done additional testing and given the rarity of the items would suggest using only 1 Guts, 1 Elixir Item, and then 3 Lynel Hoofs or Horns. Much better optimization of the rarer guts.

Comment: Indeed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7RaSWuaVcc 2330 rupees is the most expensive elixir I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I personally hunt for Raw Gourmet Meat and Raw Prime Meat mainly around the snowy north west fields of the map from wolves, moose and the fur rhinos using boomerangs on foot or halberds and spears on horse back (quick press of the X button to jump dismount and gather before they freeze in colder weather). I gather weapons from the Ice Lizalfos in the area (fire arrows ftw here, use dismount quick draw if riding your horse).

I cook a **Meat Skewer** from **4 Raw Gourmet** and **1 Raw Prime Meat** to get a 25+ Skewer **worth** **440**. I look at it as 100 per each Gourmet and 40 for the Prime and I can cook it near **Beedle** and sell it as many times a day as I want, Cheers Beedle. Hope this helps, I haven't really looked too far into other recipes because this just worked well for me early on.

Answer (score 1):

Tried and true:

- 2 x Raw Gourmet Meat
- 2 x Rock Salt
- 1 x Hearty Truffle

= 230 Rupees

I sold mine to the market lady on the south eastern beach but I've sold them elsewhere too. I feel like I ran across a higher price selling meal but can't remember the recipe...I think it was a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some poking around, and while the numbers in @Pyritie seem reasonable, I feel like there's got to be a way to game the system, at least given what we know about "rounding".  So I did some playing around with some single items, and found that a single apple (3 rupee sell price) sells for 10 rupees when cooked, for a grand total "profit" value of 3.33x.  Interestingly, if you cook 5 of them, you get an item that sells for 50 rupees, for a true multiplier of also 3.33x.  However, you can do better :)

A single acorn can sell for 2 rupees, and due to some vagaries at the low end, still sells for 8 rupees when cooked, for a *multiplier* of 4x, which is the highest that I've seen so far.  Interestingly, 5 of them sell for only 30 rupees, which certainly follows the right pattern (namely 5*2=10, and sells for 28 rounded to 30 rupees), for a profit *multiplier* of 3x, which is less than the 4x you get by cooking just 1.

The system favors cheaper items than more expensive items due to weirdness of rounding at low numbers.  While this gives you the maximum *margin* of difference between the ingredient sell price and the cooked value that I've found so far, it's *not* fast to do, however.  But you do make more total difference between sale price of ingredients vs. selling price of cooked food, that way than other things that I've come across.  Perhaps a more in-depth way to figure it out would be good.  If you can find 1000 rupees worth of acorns (500 of them), they'll sell for 4000 rupees, which is more than any other set of combination of items with an ingredient sale price of 1000 will sell for.  Apples (and other 3 rupee base price items) will sell for up to 3333 rupees.  250 of 4 rupee base items will sell for about 3000 rupees cooked (when combined into 5 items, only 2500 otherwise), and everything else is between 2800 and 3000.  Very time consuming (how the heck are you going to find 500 acorns, plus then cook *one* at a time, then vendor 500 items), but maximizes profits at the expense of time.

Generally, the post that @Pyritie made is correct, though.

Answer (score -1):

5 raw gourmet meats cooked = full recovery meat skewer= $490 best ive found so far other than a $500 diamond

Comment: It's not a big difference in value, but there's a dude at Outskirts Stables that will beat this - he offers 100/raw gourmet meat. (With a daily limit on how many he'll buy, sadly.)

Answer (score -2):

Five endura carrots cooked at blood moon sells for 420 rupees.

Answer (score -3):

1 raw gourmet meat + 4 endura carrots = 440 rupees.

Video [here](https://twitter.com/fredrikaverpil/status/922890654237069312).