# Does salting your cooking change the effects/regen hearts of a recipe?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Does adding rock salt to a recipe add any hearts or change the effect comparing it to the same recipe but without the rock salt?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rock Salt increases the duration of whatever effects your meal has. If you are just using food to restore hearts, Rock Salt has no effect.

**Fish Skewer**

- Hyrule Bass

Restores 2 Hearts

**Salt-Grilled Fish**

- Hyrule Bass
- Rock Salt

Restores 2 hearts

On the other hand, if you have a duration-based effect, it will increase the duration.

**Mighty Fish Skewer**

- Mighty Porgy

Restores 2 Hearts, Small Attack Buff 0:50

**Mighty Salt-Grilled Fish**

- Mighty Porgy
- Rock Salt

Restores 2 hearts, Small Attack Buff 1:50

**Mighty Salt-Grilled Fish**

- Mighty Porgy
- Rock Salt
- Rock Salt

Restores 2 hearts, Small Attack Buff 2:20 (All additional Rock Salts only add +0:30 seconds, instead of +1:00 from the first)

Comment: In general, the "description" of the meal is irrelevant -- the effects of a meal are determined solely by the ingredients, and I've never seen any "ingredient synergy" where using 2 materials in combination results in a greater sum effect.

Comment: Does anyone know about the technical format of the recipes? If I were to mod in recipes, could I add ingredient synergies "out of the box", or would I need to ASM into the recipe engine itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Rock salt amplifies whatever effect you're aiming for, whether it be healing, heat resistance, or something else.

Comment: A better answer here would give some examples. I've wondered about this myself, but never was too bothered.