# Great Plateau Only Recipes

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I am just starting playing Zelda Breath if the Wild. I have access to the entire great plateau, and I would like to cook as many recipes as I can before I move on so that I am well equipped and am in a good position to sell stuff for rupees. What are all the recipes that can be made from ingredients found in the great plateau?

Comment: Asking for lists is not considered a good type of question here. Apart from that, selling food does not pay that well. You should consider jumping into your adventure without a food cart ;)

Comment: @Ian Selling food is the easiest and fastest way to make money

Comment: @Pyritie Yes and no. Definitely not with ingredients from the Great Plateau. Elixirs with certain added ingredients are a nice method. Snow bowling has been known to be profitable as well. [Reddit link with more methods](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/70g02x/which_rupee_farming_method_is_best/), [Reddit link to dragon farming](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5zc42c/comprehensive_dragon_farming_guide/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  From what I gather, meat skewers is the way to go, and meat is readily available in the great plateau if you are willing to kill animals for it.  I think I'll basically spend several days in the great plateau, gathering as many items as I can, and then once I have all of those items make my own google sheets to organize them.  Then I'll make it public and share it.

Comment: You're better off just leaving the great plateau as soon as you can. There's several grades of meat in the game, and the meat you get from boars in the great plateau isn't worth very much. You won't need a massive pile of money as soon as you leave.

Comment: I agree with @Pyritie. Just leave the Great Plateau, there is not much of value there. You will find plenty of more interesting and valuable stuff down in Hyrule.

Comment: This game is set up pretty well to avoid unnecessary grinding.  By the time you *need lots of money* for anything, you will probably *have lots of money* anyway, just from playing the game.

Comment: Talus farming is also much better for Great Plateau based money than cooking.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need recipes to cook. Any 5 edible items together will produce food, and any critter(s) + monster part(s) will produce a potion.

[The only thing that matters for selling your food is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302414/what-are-the-most-profitable-meals-and-elixirs-i-can-cook?rq=1):

- How much each item that goes into the food is worth
- How many items you used