# How do I make a high-level dish?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

What makes a dish grant a low, mid, or high level buff? I can only seem to make low-level cold/heat resistance dishes by cooking five of the same ingredient. I’d like to sneak around Hebra in my Sheika armor.

Comment: related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302414/183611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are apps that can help you with recipes for your game, that can be downloaded on the Google Play/App Store.

For effective recipes, the best thing you can introduce is Dragon Horn Shards into your recipe. E.g., a Lizalfos Horn, and 3 Warm Darner will create a high level Cold Resistance elixir, that lasts for 8 minutes. However, if you also incorporate a Dragon Horn into the recipe, it will last for 30 minutes.

Additionally, you can also equip a fire weapon which will help keep you warm.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few less than clear things about cooking in the game. It comes down to potency, effect, healing, and duration. Potency and effect are tied together, while duration and healing is not.

The Hebra area is cold, frequently dipping into a high level cold effect. To create foods or elixirs that can provide this protection, you need 6 points (values needed change between effects). Different foods and elixir ingredients have different potency levels.

If you were to use your spicy peppers, even using all 5 you would only reach a potency amount of 5 giving you a low level warming effect for 12:30, which fails to reach the 6 needed for a stronger effect. If you were to replace one of those peppers with a Sunshroom you would now have that stronger warming effect, but it still lasts 12:30 because they both provide the same duration boost.

I only found out about this type of information a few weeks ago thanks to [this video on youtub](https://youtu.be/QAN-f7j82gQ)e. It was an excellent starting point as it covered the potency levels required for effects. I found it incomplete as it did not cover elixirs and other things so I have been expanding my own, as well as verifying that information and understanding it better.

Answer (score 1):

A good recipe that I often use is three Sunshrooms. You can cook up some Spicy Mushroom Skewer with a level two cold resistance and 7:30 duration.

Satori Mountain (Mogg Latan Shrine) has a huge amounts of shrooms, as I've read on reddit.

If you want longer duration (30 minutes!), you'll need a shard of Faroshs Horn.

Get a Golden Bow (Gerudo Town South-east wall, chest hidden in a pile of garbage: use magnesis), a boatload of arrows and a Fireblade (north west of Death Mountain, in the camp under the Great Eldin Skeleton). Then go to the Shoda Sah Shrine below the Riola Spring in Faron Region. North of the Riola Spring there's a ledge you can hide under from potential rain. Put down a bundle of wood and light it with your Flameblade. Wait for morning and jump and glide as soon as Farosh shows up and the updrafts start. Instantly draw your bow and aim for the horn. You should be able to get about 3 horns per minute this way.

Now cook up some Spicy Mushroom Skewer with a level two cold resistance and 30 minutes duration.

I hope this is helpful and elaborate enough :D